# Laravel-5.4 Polymorphic relation returns empty array

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a Laravel-5.4 project. I've three tables `users`, `articles` and `comments` in my database.

Screenshot of `articles` table:

[image: articles table]

Screenshot of `comments` table:

[image: comments table]

`Article` model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function comments() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

`Comment` model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

`ArticleController` contains the following method:

```
public function showComments() {
    return Article::find(1)->comments;
}
```

Above `showComments()` method returns `[]` (empty array). I want to return all the comments of the article which has `id=1`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `commentable_type` column should store the model name fully namespaced, such as `App\User`. Did you enter this information in manually? Try changing it to `App\User`, `App\Article` etc and see if that works.

You can create a `morphMap` in the boot method of your `AppServiceProvider` to alias these namespaces to a more descriptive name, as you have done here.

```
public function boot()
{
    Relation::morphMap([
        'User' => 'App\User',
        // etc
    ]);
}
```

To import `Relation`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
```